# Implement API with calls that return an item from a list, or the first item in the list

Tags: c#, collections

I have a large library of code that assumes fields contain a single value of class T. Unfortunately, a new client requires us to have those fields point to List(Of T). I can change the field type, but then all the older code breaks.

In VB I would solve this this way:

```
Private theList As List(Of T) = new List(Of T)
Public ReadOnly Property Thing() As T
  Get
     Return theList(0)
  End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Thing(i As Integer) As T
  Get
     Return theList(i) 'yes, this should throw
  End Get
End Property
```

This relies on VB's ability to have multiple properties with the same name, and the overloading the parenthesis for both parameter passing and indexing. However, C# uses braces for the later, and does not have anything corresponding to a parameterized property. Instead, they have "this[]", and since that name is private you cannot have a "this" with no parameter and another with one (that is true, right?).

But how would I do this in C#? I suspect I can do this with a template, but I'm a bit lost how it would look. I can imagine a List(Of T) subclass with a `this[]`, but then I'm not sure how I would implement the accessors in the other classes so that I still have `Thing` and `Thing[i]`. And one caveat, these objects are often used from VBA so it needs to be COM-exportable.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're asking. Can you show some example code that you currently have, and some example calls or results as you would like to get them?

Comment: The VB examples aren't returning a single value vs. returning a list, they're both returning a single value, just one returns the first value and the other returns an indexed value.
You can't change the datatype of the existing properties, you would have to add new properties that expose a Collection<T>

Comment: That's right @MichaelBlackburn, they both return a single item. However, the second version has a "list aware" API. That is, the callee knows there is more than one item and can ask for a particular item in the list. In the first example, the callee does not know there is a list, and always expects the first item.

Comment: This is an example of why you depend on an abstraction and not a concrete type. If you had an interface, you could write a new implementation of the interface for the new client that used a list as a backing store instead of a single T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method to access the property instead if the getter itself.
For example:

```
class Eg
{
    List<T> Test { get; set; }

    T GetTest()
    {
        return Test[0];
    }

    T GetTest(int index)
    {
        return Test[index];
    }
}
```

You would then access the property like so (and if wanted you could remove the getter):

```
Eg eg = new Eg();
T t = eg.GetTest();
```

or

```
T t = eg.GetTest(i);
```

Comment: This is just what I was thinking along the lines of, but would this not lose enumeration? Or perhaps I wrap that as well?

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Not perfect, but working is working!

Answer (score 1):

I would Suggest using FirstOrDefault from the Linq library, as List[0] will error on an empty list andd also means that you can't switch to any other datatype that doesn't support index reading

```
private List<T> items = new List<T>();

public T Item
{
    get { return items.FirstOrDefault(); }
}

public List<T> Items
{
    get { return items; }
}
```

however properties don't accept parametrisation except in the form of a this Property

if you used a method for this then that will work eg

```
public T GetData()
{
    get { return items.FirstOrDrfault(); }
}

public T GetData(int index)
{
    get { return items[index]; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make your class provide functionality to a new client, you might need to change your design to have them depend on an Interface, rather than the specific implementation of the class.

That said, if sounds like your new client needs a different class, which might contain a collection of your old class, rather than changing your class to fit the new client.